# How to arrange points in a polygon?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matplotlib, attributes, polygon

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y = np.arange(0,10,.01)
x1 = y / np.sqrt(3)
x2 = (y - (5 * np.sqrt(3))) / (-np.sqrt(3))

plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.ylim(0,5)

poly = ax.fill_betweenx(y,x1,x2,where= y <= 2.5*np.sqrt(3))

plt.show(plot)
```

So far all I've been able to manage is create the polygon itself. I am trying to put a list of points in the triangle. I am trying to recreate Sierpinski's Triangle from the Chaos Game video from Numberphile on YouTube. I would like to create an array of points that I could plot onto a triangle with known vertexes. I am just unsure if the method I am doing it in is correct or efficient.

I tried using the PolyCollection documentation but I was receiving errors like I was using the wrong attributes and incorrect functions, I am pretty new to python so I was unsure of how to put together the stuff before the function get_closed() or get_path().

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def mid_point(p1, p2):
    # calculating mid_point
    return (p1 + p2)/2


# define A, B and C vertexes
pa = [2.5, 4.5]
pb = [5.0, 0.0]
pc = [0.2, 0.5]

# number iterations
ni = 1000

# markers/points properties
color = 'blue'
marker_size = 1

# vertexes points
vert = np.array([pa, pb, pc])

# starting point at AB line
start_point = mid_point(vert[0], vert[1])

# plot A, B, C
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(vert[:, 0], vert[:, 1], 
        ls='', 
        marker='o', 
        c=color, 
        markersize=marker_size)

# matrix others points
others = np.zeros((ni+1, 2))
others[0] = start_point 
for i in range(ni):
    chosen = np.random.randint(0, 3)
    others[i+1] = mid_point(others[i], vert[chosen])

# plot others points
ax.plot(others[:, 0], others[:, 1], 
        ls='', 
        marker='o', 
        c=color, 
        markersize=marker_size)

plt.show()
```

[image]